# Angular2 Google Maps panTo not working (does nothing)

Tags: angular, angular-google-maps

I'm using Angular Google Maps (latest `@agm/core`) but can't get `panTo` or `setCenter` to work it simply does nothing.

I import `GoogleMapsAPIWrapper` like this:

```
import { GoogleMapsAPIWrapper } from '@agm/core';
```

I then inject it into my constructor:

```
constructor(
injector: Injector,
private _wrapper: GoogleMapsAPIWrapper
){
super(injector);
}
```

Then I try to call the above method in a function like so:

```
resetMap():void
{
  this._wrapper.setCenter({lat:53.097900,
  lng:-1.661963});
  this._wrapper.panTo({lat:53.097900,
  lng:-1.661963});
}
```

I have also tried referencing the map as a ViewChild of type AgmMap but there is no public property to setCenter or panTo, as below;

```
@ViewChild('agmMap') agmMap:AgmMap;
```

Is there a way I can reference the google map control directly instead of the angular wrapper?

Please can anyone advise what I'm doing wrong? or how I am meant to reference the map to call methods against it.

Comment: I'm having similar frustrations with this library. Any luck on this? I see it's been some time.

Comment: Everything can be done by changing the various properties on the `@ViewChild`, and settings `usePanning` to true, but I'd much rather use the actual panTo method. Your way of using a child components seems too convoluted